# Inserting text to make every row start the same way

Tags: string, sed, replace, row

I have a file that contains rows with various bits of information. Unfortunately, the file was compiled from many different sources so some of the rows have more information than others:

```
1_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 1
2_10090 Mus musculus Gene 2
3_10090 (house mouse) Gene 3
4_10090 Gene 4
```

My desired output is:

```
1_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 1
2_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 2
3_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 3
4_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 4
```

I thought to use sed to replace every line that contains _10090 followed by a character other than 'M' with 'Mus musculus' (and then do the same for those that don't contain (house mouse)):

```
sed 's/_10090 [^M]/_10090 Mus musculus /g'
```

But this, of course, replaces the character after 10090 which I want to retain:

```
1_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 1
2_10090 Mus musculus Gene 2
3_10090 Mus musculus house mouse) Gene 3
4_10090 Mus musculus ene 4
```

How might I go about ensuring that every line starts with

```
#_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse)
```

where # is different between every row and some lines already contain this string and others contain parts of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `(house mouse)` a fixed string, or can there be anything inside `(...)`?

Comment: Please check if https://ideone.com/52hZt6 works for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew (house mouse) is a fixed string. The only things varying are the characters that occur before _10090 and the characters that occur after (house mouse)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried and I think that did the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: I added the approach explanation in my answer below.

Comment: If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/_10090( Mus musculus)?( \(house mouse\))? /_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) /g' file
```

The approach is slightly different since your described logic does not help achieve the expected results. Namely, I match an optional `' Mus musculus'` and then an optional `' (house mouse)'` substrings after a `_10090` substring (with a space after) and add (back, if they were present) these substrings in the substitution pattern.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/52hZt6):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='1_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 1
2_10090 Mus musculus Gene 2
3_10090 (house mouse) Gene 3
4_10090 Gene 4'
sed -E 's/_10090( Mus musculus)?( \(house mouse\))? /_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) /g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
1_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 1
2_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 2
3_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 3
4_10090 Mus musculus (house mouse) Gene 4
```